# Do I really need IAM tool?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-iam, google-iam

I have a web application (using Spring Boot).  I am thinking to use some 3rd party tool for Authentication/Authorization purpose, instead of handling Identity logic myself.. and my web-app is a simple application.

So, do you think whether some IAM tool (Identity and Access Management) is over-burden for my simple web application? or do you suggest me to create Authorization Server myself, instead of some any IAM tool?

Comment: Use a third-party identity provider such as Okta, Auth0, etc. They are easy to use, have good libraries and quick start guides. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/15/spring-boot-login-options

Comment: @JohnHanley Seems both Okta and Autho charging lot just to get some Authentication/Authorization for a web-app

Comment: @JohnHanley May I know why did you suggested me to use 3rd party tool, instead of asking me to write Authorizations server code myself? Any great reason?

Comment: I included several reasons in my comment. Writing a secure identity server is very hard. If your goal is to master OAuth, then write your own. Both Okta, Auth0, etc have free tiers. One item, do not confuse IAM with Identity Services. They are not the same. I would not use AWS IAM to provide authentication for my website. You could look at Amazon Cognito also, which is in the same product line as Okta, Auth0, etc. There is a good reason that Identity Providers such as Google, Facebook, etc are so popular. Investigate why before deciding to recreate their products.

Comment: @JohnHanley At first, many thanks for your suggestion, could you please suggest me which is BEST FREE IAM tool out of many, for my web-app? I just checked okta, its showing $0 for 1000 MAU and thereafter prices going high.. All my users are basically web users, not any Internal employees or External customer.. So does web-users considered as external customers?

Comment: @JohnHanley Auth0 is charging after 1000 users got added into their database... so, any forever free IAM Best Tool , any idea? or atleast any tool which gives me 1 year complete free, providing access all features.

Comment: Google, Facebook, etc are free. If you want to control your own Identity service, then you will need to create/subscribe/pay for one.

Comment: @JohnHanley Amazon Cognito seems to be like completely free.. some queries: 1)Does IAM tool maintain db's to store our users? If yes, are we really sure that users not gonna be deleted from DB's in anyway? 2)whats the difference between IAM and Identity Service?  3) I didnt find any Facebook IAM tool ?

Comment: Please do not use Stack Overflow as a chat service. Research your issue, then create well defined "on-topic" questions. I have given you enough advice to get you started. Google Search is your friend here.

Comment: OK fine, At first, Really Many Thanks @JohnHanley  for your suggestions and link... Please answer this final query ie.,: Does IAM tools maintain db's to store our users? If yes, are we really sure that some 50,000 users not gonna be lose from DB's in anyway?

Comment: @JohnHanley I need some help: How to  restrict access to my own custom api,using AWS Cognito? Iam not finding any documentation for that.. Any idea, pls?

Comment: Create a new question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Actually  already created, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363833/how-to-restrict-custom-api-access-using-aws-cognito?noredirect=1#comment108573521_61363833

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you please take sometime and reply for above link