# How to Restrict Custom api access using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using Spring Boot in my application. While searching for some IAM tools, I actually liked Auth0, but iam not affordable their pricing. So, I found another called `AWS Cognito`.

Below is Auth0 to restrict our custom access api

```
 https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/restrict-access-api
```

Currently, I am trying to restrict access API using AWS cognito, but I am not finding correct documentation to achieve this. Can anyone please tell me whether restricting api access can be possible using aws cognito.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to restrict access to your own custom api? Do you want to restrict access to all api methods, or only to a certain subset of them. And when you restrict access, do you want that to be for all users, or do you want different user types that have different levels of access?

Comment: @lemming yes,  trying to restrict access to my own custom api, how can we achieve this using aws cognito? At first, is that even possible to restrict custom api using aws cognito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much fine-grained control you want over the access to your api.

*Allow or Deny Scenario*

In some cases, you either want to block someone completely, or give them access to all of your api. In this all or nothing scenario, the simplest route would be to use Cognito User Pools on their own to authorize your users. Cognito User Pools is just used to authenticate the user (are they who they say they are), and to provide tools to make sign up, and sign in easier.

If the user passes authentication, then you can pass one of the tokens returned by cognito user pools (the identity token) to API Gateway. As long as you have set up your api methods to have the Cognito User Pools authorizer in API Gateway, then this is enough for them to accept the identity token as authorization to access the methods.

*Fine-Grained Access*

However, in other cases, you need more fine-grained control. You may want all authenticated users to have access to a certain subset of your api methods, but only admins to have access to more restricted methods.

In this case, you will also need to use Cognito Identity Pools, to define *user roles* (e.g. UNAUTHENTICATED_USER, PAID_USER, ADMIN etc), and their associated *IAM roles*, which will have policies that give them access, or deny them access to various parts of your api.

You then set the authorizer for your api gateway resources to be AWS_IAM (instead of Cognito User Pools as in the all or nothing example above). And API Gateway will use the role credentials obtained from the Cognito Identity Pool to determine if the current user's role has the permissions to access the requested resource.

For example, perhaps your PAID_USER user role, will have the following IAM role attached:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:fjfkdlsjflds/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:fjfkdlsjflds/*/admin/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This gives them access to your api, apart from the api methods (resources) that you have set up under */admin/*.

I highly recommend [this AWS reinvent talk on Serverless Authentication and Authorization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZqG7HjT2AQ&t=2362s), which goes over these options with some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand What you are trying to do is to resolve the authorization for your APIs. Cognito comes to picture in case of Authentication (Instead of your own database and user handling it supports everything). By using Cognito you can create a User pool and Identity pool to handle the User authentication and create the access token for the authorization for subsequent API calls. The following you need to do 
1) Register with AWS Cognito and create a user management pool and Identitiy pool
2) Create a spring boot app (as you mentioned spring boot in your stack) for authentication.
3) Add spring security dependency
4) Register the appln as a resource app in COgnito
5) Do the authentication and return back the token you generated.
6) Create another application (for actual business you may have multiple microservices)
7) Register those spring boot app as resource server in cognito
8) Add the spring security dependency on the new app
9) Create a handler by extending WebSecurityConfigAdaper and override configure
10) Create a filter by extending OncePerRequestFilter
11) Authenticate the token by checking the claims 
12) Restrict the API access to all calls in cofigure method of configurer

Comment: Hey thanks for brief reply.. I heard somewhere like we can use AWS API Gateway service for Authorization, you aware of this..? I still ddnt yet went thrugh this, but have to..