# AWS Cognito check if logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I already have an endpoint where users can login, this endpoint currently only returns the body of the response from my custom JWT token validator. What I want now is that other endpoints in my app cannot be accessed by users that are not logged in, these users will be redirected to the login page.
How can I approach this?

Comment: You may be able to bring in the Auth component (example in Typescript)
`import { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';`
then check the authenticated user exists
`get isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean|any> {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(() => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return false;
    });
  }`
If not, redirect to the login configured in Cognito
`signIn(): void {
    const url = `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/login?client_id=${AUTH_CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${AUTH_CALLBACK_URL}`;
    window.location.assign(url);
  }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit generic. Just for orientation you have to use User Pools, based on Roles. You may refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363833/how-to-restrict-custom-api-access-using-aws-cognito).